# Doggie "Kisses" on Tisha b'Av when Rechitza (Washing) is Forbidden

Tags: halacha, animals, tisha-bav

Several authorities forbid washing on the Ninth of Av, and many of those same authorities often require one to sit on the floor or a low stool during that evening and morning. However, I own a dog and it likes to kiss [lick] me extensively, as dogs tend to do. Could this be considered washing? Is it even worse to sit on a low chair if the dog is more likely to kiss me when I am closer to the ground?

Comment: I almost wrote Retzichah, which would have been really ironic.

Comment: Yuk. (sorry...)

Comment: @Dave - It's not disgusting, I love my puppy!

Comment: That's what the sorry was for.

Comment: Why do we even have a [tag:pets] tag?

Comment: You might even ask if you're allowed to be around your dog until mid-day... surely the animal brings you a lot of joy, since you're willing to put up with the kisses.

Comment: Several authorities? I didn't know anyone permitted washing.

Comment: (Serious question) Do you feel cleaner after s/he slobbers all over you?

Comment: @SethJ - Any instance that would override a derabbanan would negate the prohibition of washing. Such as [kavod habriyot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kavod_HaBriyot#Talmudic_context).

Comment: @DoubleAA - Personally, I do feel cleaner.

Comment: @AdamMosheh, isn't that instance outside the framework of the question, though?

Comment: If the question were, "May I wash gross doggy slobber off of my hands and face after getting "kissed" by my dog," I'd give it a +1.

Comment: @SethJ - I think the answer to that question is obvious though.

Comment: @SethJ - the second question. The first, I'm not sure if it is relevant to the framework of it. It probably depends, don't you think?

Comment: @AdamMosheh, you're basically asking if it counts as washing (*yech*). If so, then the exceptions to allow it would be the same as the exceptions that allow washing with water. So, I don't think any caveats about DeRabbanans really apply to the question at hand. It's really a question of comparison, more than a question of permissibility.