# Wiping hands on Tisha b'Av

Tags: halacha, mourning-aveilus, netilat-yadayim-washing, tisha-bav, inuy-affliction

Since many authorities permit [wiping the hands](http://www.yonanewman.org/kizzur/kizzur2.html#6) if one does not have water to wash with (when washing for bread), is one forbidden to wipe their hands on Tisha b'Av?

Comment: Inspired by [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17812/doggie-kisses-on-tisha-bav-when-rechitza-washing-is-forbidden).

Comment: Your saying, since wiping=cleaning it should be forbidden to wipe? I don't follow why it should be assur. It's permitted to clean dirt off one's body even with water!

Comment: @DoubleAA nu so you're not covered in dirt - the question is should one be careful not to wipe the hands on a towel or the pants or something on Tisha b'Av, just as one would be careful not to wash one's hands.

Comment: If you're not wiping off dirt, then why are you wiping? For pleasure? I don't even know what that means.

Comment: @DoubleAA if there needs to be a *reason* for the wiping or washing and accidental or non-functional actions aren't a problem, answer that with a citation :)

Comment: Why do you keep talking about hands? Perhaps you should be careful that your torso doesn't wipe against your shirt?

Answer (score 7):

See [here](http://vbm-torah.org/archive/moadim69/24-69moed.htm),

> One may dry his hands on a towel and then use the damp towel to clean
>   his eyes and face, as the towel isn’t wet enough to impart enough
>   water to wet something else (tofach al menat le-hatpiach) ([Shulchan
>   Arukh 554:11](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49628&st=&pgnum=62)). (If one must actually clean one’s eyes in the morning,
>   it is permitted to do so normally, as it is no different than washing
>   any other part of the body which has become soiled.) **Furthermore,
>   the Rama ([ibid. 14](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49628&st=&pgnum=62)) writes that one may pre-soak cloths before Tisha
>   Be-av, remove them, and then use them to clean his face, hands, and
>   feet. Even if one’s intention is for pleasure, this is permitted
>   because he already squeezed the water out of the cloths.**

The text in bold implies that one may wipe one’s hands on Tisha b'Av.

Comment: See also the Rama [613:9](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49628&st=&pgnum=153) regarding Yom Kippur.